# Use secondary/backup observable as long as primary observable hasn't emitted any value

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

The following is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
|--------------------A-A-A-A-A-A| primary (behavior subject)
|-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-| secondary (flowable)
|-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-BA-A-A-A-A-A| result (flowable)
```

Basically, I'm waiting for user input (through primary observable) but I would like to provide system generated values if user hasn't inputted anything yet. Once user input is received, the secondary observable will not be used anymore.

I looked into `switchIfEmpty` and `combineLatest` but they don't fit my needs because:

1. **switchIfEmpty** only works if primary observable signals onComplete.
2. **combineLatest** only works if both observables emit a value

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm never sure if it's the easiest or most elegant way to do it, but this works:

```
const a = Observable.interval(5000);
const b = Observable.interval(1000);

const sharedA = a.shareReplay(1);

const result = b.takeUntil(sharedA).concat(sharedA);
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/f2qICCbyMbAhwoBNhg8V?p=preview)

Another, maybe simple way, would be

```
const sharedA = a.share();
const result = b.takeUntil(sharedA).merge(sharedA);
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/4pV5BsCA68M2wFJ2tbJt?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to return to observable b? (i.e reset observable a as if it hadn't emitted any items)?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by that. You don't reset observables. They emit, then they complete or error, then they're done.

Comment: So here is a concrete example: A user wants to order a ride. He may set up a pickup location manually (observable a), otherwise we provide gps location (observable b) as pickup location. Now if the user taps "my location" button on the map, then we would like to return to gps location as provider. I'm trying to solve this using a single observable that is observed from multiple places, so I can't really recreate it.

Comment: I don't even understand where observables fit in this example. None of what you described looks like a stream of events to me. You just have one location, replaced by another when the user clicks a button, and replaced again when the user clicks another button.

Comment: Well this location is observed from multiple places, and I prefer providing an observable for it instead of listeners and callbacks. Don't observables fit in this example? Also GPS location updates arrive asynchronously.

Comment: Maybe all you want is a subject for your location, and when you click a button, you emit the user's picked location or the gps location (depending on the user's choice) on this subject.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148447/discussion-between-nima-and-jb-nizet).

Answer (score 0):

In covering your comments on the accepted answer... Namely:

> A user wants to order a ride. He may set up a pickup location manually (observable a), otherwise we provide gps location (observable b) as pickup location. Now if the user taps "my location" button on the map, then we would like to return to gps location as provider.

You have three source streams:

- a: Current GPS location (stream of lat/lon pairs.)
- b: Manually chosen lat/lon (stream of lat/lon pairs.)
- c: A button tap (stream of void.)

I wrote this in RxSwift rather than RxJava, but hopefully you can translate:

```
extension Observable {
    static func switchBetween(_ a: Observable<Element>, _ b: Observable<Element>, using trigger: Observable<Void>) -> Observable<Element> {
        return Observable.create { observer in
            let lock = NSRecursiveLock()
            var withB = false
            let disposeA = a.subscribe({ event in
                if withB == false {
                    observer.on(event)
                }
            })
            let disposeB = b.subscribe({ event in
                lock.lock(); defer { lock.unlock() }
                withB = true
                observer.on(event)
            })
            let disposeTrigger = trigger.subscribe({ event in
                if case .next = event {
                    lock.lock(); defer { lock.unlock() }
                    withB = false
                }
            })
            return Disposables.create(disposeA, disposeB, disposeTrigger)
        }
    }
}
```

It can be called like this:

```
Observable.switchBetween(a, b, using: c)
```